# Resizing partitions/moving /u01 oracle directory

Tags: linux, partition, oracle-11g

I've got a test server recently set up at work which has oracle installed under /u01 - but without realising it, I've set the root partition to be ~50GB, so have filled the partition very quickly once I started loading tablespaces.

The /home partition is ~1.8TB with ~1.4TB free. Basically I'm trying to work out either
1) How to resize the /home and /(root) partitions
2) How to move the /u01 folder to /home/oracle/u01 or similar without Oracle going mental

I can't change the partitions while the server is running, presumably... would my best bet be to use a live CD or something to resize partitions, or is it possible to resize while running? Or alternatively, can I move Oracle's base folder without causing too much trouble

Thanks!

Comment: Or would the intelligent move be to make new datafiles on /home, then copy the existing tablespaces from the datafiles on /(root) to the datafiles on /home?

Comment: Which OS? Are you using logical volume management? What is the partition table? Can your DBA tell Oracle to use tablespaces elsewhere? Can you use a bind mount to use space from elsewhere under /u01? If this is a test server, why can you not stop it? If this is a test server, why not start again from scratch?

Comment: What filesystems? Are you using LVM?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I'd mentioned the OS. It's Oracle Linux 6, and using ext4. I believe I'm using logical volume management - there's an option for it under Webmin, at any rate. As far as I'm aware I have one physical volume, one volume group and 3 logical volumes (root, home and swap), but this may be wrong as I'm not used to linux terminology. I've mentioned moving the tablespaces, but I'm new to oracle too (small company, so I've sort of fallen into the task).

How would I use a bind mount to use space from elsewhere? And I can't stop it because the machine is in use for other things.

Comment: Simplest -- create /u02 (or whatever) somewhere with more space and tell Oracle to use that instead (or as well as /u01).

Comment: Just create a folder, or create a mount point? Don't I need another logical volume to add another mount point? I've suggested to the DBAs to create/use datafiles on the /home logical volume.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new directory for Oracle in the 1.8TB /home. Then either (a) have your DBA tell Oracle to use that; or (b) shutdown Oracle, move the contents of /u01 to this new directory, remove /u01 and recreate /u01 as a symbolic link to the new directory.

Comment: I hadn't thought of b, thanks. That sounds neater as it moves everything. I'll check what they want to do (I know very little about Oracle)